# "Network services system are not compatible with this version ." Debian 8

Tags: linux, networking, debian

Helllo, I'm using Debian 8 and it runs correctly, but I restart my computer after installing icons and gnome shell extensions and that happened :(
any ideas?

Translate to English "Network services system are not compatible with this version"

Thank you for help

[image: Any ideas?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are incompatibilities, I would suggest you run the 'upgrade manager', and let it check if there are packages which have to be update.

How did you install the icons and what did you install from gnome? An extension?

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install network-manager
```

I think your installation, or your last update, was interrupted and incomplete.

Comment: The numix icons, and put them at /usr/share/icons ahd yes shell extension from https://extensions.gnome.org/

Comment: Edited the reply above.